# A detailed question in Bott&Tu

Tags: differential-geometry

In Bott&Tu:《Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology》 p.26,there is a statement:

(b) $\Omega_{c}^{\ast}$  is a covariant functor under inclusions of open sets

Obviously for any two arbitary open sets in a manifold,there may be no inclusion between them,so here comes the question:

What is the category mentioned here exactly?

If we don't specify the category,does a functor make sense?

I'm quite confused,thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to fix some manifold $M$, then the category in question has for objects the open sets of $M$, and there is a (unique) morphism from $U$ to $V$ iff $U \subset V$. In other words, it's the poset of open subsets of $M$.

Comment: I don't get it,the definition of a category requires that for any two objects there is a set of morphisms between them...

Comment: @CWeid: that set of morphisms doesn't have to be non-empty. I don't have the reference in front of me and your question doesn't contain enough details to answer it alone, but this answer seems quite possibly correct to me.

Comment: @CWeid: If $U \subset V$ then $\hom(U,V)$ is a singleton, otherwise it's the empty set.